# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor, error

Tags: oracle, jdbc

```
11:30:42,691 ERROR IdTableHelper:105 - Unable obtain JDBC Connection
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

For some reason i'm starting my Java application in Tomcat v9.0 and jdbc is giving me error. I can connect throw Dbeaver to the Oracle database, but can't from Eclipse right now.

```
_jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
_jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@esfbcnoda01.ind.local:1521:JUNDESAB
```

I tried too:

```
_jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@esfbcnoda01.ind.local:1521/JUNDESAB
```

but is not working

Comment: How is the connection in Dbeaver configured?

Comment: @JustinCave I can access with this url jdbc:oracle:thin:@esfbcnoda01.ind.local:1521/JUNDESAB in Dbeaver

Comment: Do you get the same error from both connection strings? Since the first one is using a SID and the second is trying to use a Service Name, I would expect the latter to throw a different error.  The normal format for a service name connection string is `jdbc:oracle:thin:[<user>/<password>]@//<host>[:<port>]/<service>` with the extra `//` after the `@`.  It isn't obvious why the DBeaver connection string would work but different versions of the JDBC driver might be more forgiving about syntax errors.

Comment: Yeah, i'm getting the same error on both.. @JustinCave

Comment: Are you trying to use a SID or a Service Name?  Service names would be recommended assuming your database supports them.  SIDs are an older approach but may be needed with legacy databases.  Do you get the same error if you use a service name connection string in the correct format?